# Kubernetes ClusterIP intermittent 502 connection refused

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

EDIT: Rebuilding a new cluster from scratch has resolved the issue.  If I switch traffic back to the old cluster, the issue remains.

So it now appears that I have a broken Kubernetes cluster which I am not certain how to detect or diagnose if it happens in the future.  Possibly: failing EC2 network adapter, failed service on one node or master, failing kube-proxy pods or other kube-system issues...

If there are any suggestions for how to detect the source of the intermittent refused connections between Pod and ClusterIP, I would love to find the root issue.

### Original issue below:

I have setup an nginx Kubernetes service (behind an external AWS LoadBalancer setup by Kubernetes).  This nginx service proxies to several inbound services by ClusterIP.

It looks like this:

ELB --->  Nginx Proxy (PodA) ---> Internal Service (PodB)

I see random 502 connection refused for one of this (very busy) services.  The nginx error logs look like this:

```
2019/10/15 19:27:57 [error] 13#0: *71355 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: X.X.X.X, server: api.acme.com, request: "GET /XYZ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://100.67.38.167:80/XYZ", host: "acme.com"
```

I get about 10-15 of these 502 errors per second (Maybe 1% of total requests).

My internal service (at clusterip 100.67.38.167) did not appear to be over capacity, but I tried scaling it anyway.  I doubled the number of pods.  The number of 502 errors remains exactly the same.

Just to be certain there was no issue with the internal service, I added a second container to its pod, running its own nginx proxy.  So the connection looks like:

ELB ---> Nginx Proxy1 (PodA) ---> Nginx Proxy2 (PodB) ---> Internal Service (PodB)

The second Nginx proxy sees zero errors.  So all of the errors appear to be between Nginx and the ClusterIP address.  Does this mean kube-proxy is over capacity?

Is there any way to determine if this is the case?

Note: This is a 14 node cluster, and adding a node to the cluster (and moving some pods over) doesn't reduce 502's either.

I have also tried: (1) adding and removing keep-alive timeouts for nginx proxy_pass.  (2) Resolving the internal service by ip address or by DNS (3) Scaling kube-dns up

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: can you provide furthermore testing/benchmarking with a classic and empty NGINX backend instead of your Internal Service?

Comment: @prometherion I'm afraid that won't be possible.  This is production traffic.  The problem does not occur with low traffic simulations, and I have not setup an empty cluster to test with massive simulated traffic.  However, I think that adding the nginx container in front of my Internal Service verifies that the Internal Service is completely irrelevant.  This nginx in the second Pod does not see any of the errors.  They are all occurring between the first Pod and the ClusterIP.

Comment: A 502 does not always mean a bad gateway. I experienced the same behavior and noted these were either dropped connections by the client or timeouts. Try increasing the timeout of your proxy or try to replicate by simulating a dropped connection.

Comment: @RodrigoLoza - The error log shows "Connection refused while connecting to upstream" and the access log shows the total request time is 0 seconds-- immediate rejection by kube-proxy

Comment: @user1724280 kube-proxy is not connection aware: it justs performs nftables/iptables/ipvs management. Please ignore that misleading comment

Comment: @prometherion.  I started a whole new cluster to handle production traffic, which resolved the issue.  However, this allowed me to perform arbitrary tests on the old cluster.  I did try an empty NGINX backend  (return 200) and the result was the same, NGINX responds successfully for every request it sees.  But the proxy Pod gets intermittent connection refused.  Also able to replicate with curl. ~5% of requests fail with 20 backend pods, and 50% of requests with one backend pod.  Doesn't matter which node the pod is on.  Clearly a failed cluster but I wish I knew HOW so that I could detect